# Setting environment variables in Erlang applications

Tags: erlang, environment, rebar

There's clearly something I don't understand about Erlang... well, among many things.

I've set up an application under Rebar called cw.I start it up and everything runs fine.

Now I want to create an environment variable so I can access the src directory. I've entered the following in cw.app.src:

```
{env, [{proj_root, "mypath/apps/cw"}]}
```

Compile, start with Rebar start.sh... everything works fine.

Now the mystery. Yesterday when I did this, I got the correct path when I entered application:get_env(cw, proj_root) in the Erlang shell. But today I get undefined.

What am I missing?

Many thanks,

LRP

Comment: Just a guess: maybe yesterday you've modified the `cw.app` instead of the `cw.app.src`?

Comment: The application must be loaded for the environment variables to be defined. Did you load or start your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`application:load(cw)` should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Did you forget `application:start(cw)` first?
If application not started, the env is undefined.